# How do I populate text fields with information from Active Directory?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, active-directory

I would like to populate some read only text fields with information from Active Directory, for example name and email address for the user who is currently logged on.

I am using **.NET Core 2.2** and getting conflicting information as to whether this is natively supported, for example, the Microsoft documentation says it isn't but the GitHub repository indicates it is. Some information indicates it's now native support, some says it's done with a compatibility library.

What should I use to perform such as task?

Thanks,

Comment: show us a links where it's said

Comment: AD supports LDAP so you can use the [Novell LDAP libraries](https://www.novell.com/documentation/developer/ldapcsharp/) - the code you will need can be found at [Authenticating against Active Directory with ASP.Net Core 2](https://www.brechtbaekelandt.net/blog/post/authenticating-against-active-directory-with-aspnet-core-2-and-managing-users)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For what I needed, the following code is what I was after, a number of other fields can be used too:

`public static String Email = UserPrincipal.Current.EmailAddress;`

I can then reference these in my Razor Pages.

This was using `System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement;` so it looks as though `System.DirectoryServices` is natively supported in .NET Core, or at least in the context I needed. I'll need to do some more digging.

Answer (score 0):

```
string userName = System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name;
string user = userName.Split('\\')[1];
string domain = userName.Split('\\')[0];
```

Comment: Why `ToLower()`?

Comment: It was part from my personal code... Removed. Thanks!